# Preventing XBMC from shutting down

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, nas, kodi

I have an ubuntu server with XBMC installed and the server connected to a TV via an HDMI cable.  To launch XBMC I am running the command:

```
sudo init xbmc
```

By using ssh to remote to the server and then running the command that way.  This seems to work fine at the time and I will be able to watch a film or a TV show.  After a few hours XBMC seems to stop running whether it is playing something or not, which means that every time I wish to watch something I have to ssh to the server and run that command.

My ideal solution would be to only have to run that command once so that I could turn the TV off and go away for an indefinite period but when I come back I can use XBMC without having to log in and run that command.

I reckon I must be starting XBMC incorrectly or perhaps there is something in the settings that I have not set properly, can anybody help?

Comment: is this a dedicated server for XBMC?

Comment: No, it is used as a testing server for other things such as websites and small programs.  Just a box I use to learn things with really.

Answer (score 1):

There are [several ways to do this](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Install_XBMC_for_Linux), depending on how is this server used (i.e., if it is a dedicated HTPC or not), an `upstart` script might be the best fit for you. This one from the same [XBMC wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/) article linked before:

```
# xbmc-upstart
# starts XBMC on startup by using xinit.
# by default runs as xbmc, to change edit below.
env USER=xbmc

description     "XBMC-barebones-upstart-script"
author          "Matt Filetto"

start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [016]

# tell upstart to respawn the process if abnormal exit
respawn

script
  exec su -c "xinit /usr/bin/xbmc --standalone -- -nocursor :0" $USER
end script
```

You can also [disable](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting) the service from autostarting, so you're still able to log in remotely via `ssh` and run XBMC.

Comment: This did seem like a promising solution, but when I went to create the file it already appeared to exist with the same content, so I am going to assume that it does not work as a solution, unless you are aware of anything else I had to do for this to work?

Comment: Do you use it to start XBMC? Because it should respawn itself on exit.

Comment: To start xbmc I just type the command: sudo xinit xbmc.  How do I start xmbc using this script instead?

Comment: As you normally would with any other service that uses [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start)

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I wasn't aware of that, I'll try it out, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the program in the background by appending an ampersand to the command.

```
sudo init xbmc --standalone -- -nocursor :0 &
```

This will ensure xbmc is not killed by a timeout without having to use screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a **workaround**: Let a cron-job check every few minutes if XMBC is still running and start it again if it is not. The corresponding bash could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ `ps u | grep xmbc | wc -l` != "2" ]; then
    screen -dm init xmbc
fi
```

Maybe you have to adjust the line count (the `"2"` part) if xmbc spawns child processes.
Depending on your setup, it could also work without `screen`.